# How to fix CURSOR_MISMATCH error. Not using all tables in entity

Tags: android, android-room

So I am using a entity in Room persistance database. I have multiple columns but only want one of them to be loaded at ActivityA. Later in ActivityB I use all other columns I made. The warning I get from Room is CURSOR_MISMATCH and wants me to Ignore the other fields, thats not what I want since I use them in ActivityB.

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "persons")
public class oPerson implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personName")
    private String personName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personRank")
    private String personRank;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAge")
    private String personAge;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAvailabilityMonday")
    private String personAvailabilityMonday;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAvailabilityTuesday")
    private String personAvailabilityTuesday;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAvailabilityWednesday")
    private String personAvailabilityWednesday;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAvailabilityThursday")
    private String personAvailabilityThursday;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAvailabilityFriday")
    private String personAvailabilityFriday;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAvailabilitySaturday")
    private String personAvailabilitySaturday;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "personAvailabilitySunday")
    private String personAvailabilitySunday;
}
```

Dao query for ActivityA:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM persons")
LiveData<List<oPerson>> getPersons();
```

Dao query for ActivityB:

```
@Query("SELECT personName, id FROM persons")
LiveData<List<oPerson>> getPersonName();
```

If I Log.I(); my Entity I get for ActivityA:

```
[Entity{id: 'actual id', name: 'actual name', rank: 'actual rank', age: 'actual age' etc...},Entity{same as first}]
```

If I log ActivityB:

```
[Entity{id: 'actual id', name: 'actual name', rank: 'null', age: 'null' etc...},Entity{same as first}]
```

So (Correct me if im wrong) in ActivityB it loads the columns I dont need aswell. I hope if I get an answer it will be something like this:

```
[Entity{id: 'actual id', name: 'actual name'},Entity{same as first}]
```

So now without the other columns.
Im not sure if this is the right way, im kinda new to Android and room persistance.

EDIT>>>
Maybe this link makes it more clear what I want: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_columns
You can see it only shows 2 columns of a database with more then 2 columns... I want this in android

Answer (score 0):

that should probably be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = :id")
LiveData<oPerson> getPerson(int id);
```

Comment: Now I get only one time my entity/item. I want all my saved entities/items but only the name that is set in my object. So only the personName (and id since I think its required).